# Is it possible in Oracle SQLDeveloper to prefetch certain tables’ metadata and keep it cached locally?

Tags: sql, caching, metadata, prefetch, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am working on a remote database which has several master tables. the meta-data & the actual data in these tables changes rarely.
When querying DB involving these tables and using certain functions (Ex: ctrl+space to auto-complete a table/column name), it takes too long to query the remote DB to fetch this data since its not cached locally.

Is there any extension/plug-in/configuration in SQLDeveloper to do this.
*(Oracle SQLDeveloper Version 1.5.1 Build MAIN-5440)*

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score -1):

1. Try to update to version 2.1
2. Use a tool like [SQuirreL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) to build your queries and then copy them into SQLDeveloper. SQuirreL caches the metadata.

Comment: The point of the question is that he wants to code in SQL Developer. Suggesting he uses another tool and copies the code in defeats the object.

Comment: I beg to differ. If the tool is wrong, it's the wrong tool and no answer in the world will change that.

Comment: Did you mean to suggest that he use Squirrel in place of SQL Developer? Because that's not how it reads.

Comment: I use several tools to work with databases because each has it's strengths. This way, I can balance the weaknesses.

Answer (score -1):

You could create a view on the local DB, that would keep the metadata local.

Comment: SQL Developer does not have a "local DB".